# Laravel Mix generate fonts into another directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I'm using `laravel-mix` which is built on the top of the `webpack`. I'm facing a problem with fonts directory. For Example, `font-awesome` package has a scss file and a font directory where all fonts are placed.

```
font-awesome:.
├───scss
│       fontawesome.scss
└───webfonts
        fa-regular-400.eot
        fa-regular-400.svg
        fa-regular-400.ttf
        fa-regular-400.woff
        fa-regular-400.woff2
```

So i place this package in my `resources/assets/sass` directory.

```
resources:.
└───asset
    └───sass
        │   main.scss
        │
        └───font-awesome (directory)
```

`main.scss` contains code:

```
@import 'font-awesome/scss/fontawesome';
```

`webpack.mix.js` contains:

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/main.scss', 'public/css/frontend.css');
```

All assets are compiled successfully. Now `public` directory has a `css` and `font` directory, which has all fonts like this.

```
public:.
│   index.php
│
├───css
│       frontend.css
│
├───fonts
│       fa-regular-400.eot
│       fa-regular-400.svg
│       fa-regular-400.ttf
│       fa-regular-400.woff
│       fa-regular-400.woff2
```

But What I want is, I don't want to compile all fonts into `public/fonts` directory i want to compile as following structure `public/fonts/vendor/font-awesome`

```
public:.
├───css
│       frontend.css
│
└───fonts
    └───vendor
        └───font-awesome
                fa-regular-400.eot
                fa-regular-400.svg
                fa-regular-400.ttf
                fa-regular-400.woff
                fa-regular-400.woff2
```

What changes that i need to change in `webpack.mix.js` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1. First Create a explicit folder structure:**

like this in your laravel project.

`public/fonts/vendor/font-awesome`

Move all your fonts from `font-awesome` package to above mention directory.

**2. Change $fa-font-path variable value:**

`font-awesome` directory has a file called `_variables.scss` inside that file there is a variable named as `$fa-font-path` change the value to something like this.

```
$fa-font-path: "/fonts/vendor/font-awesome" !default;
```

Compile your assets it would work.

Answer (score 23):

If you want to use the laravel-mix and try to change `public/fonts` to `public/assets/fonts` directory,
You can use this code in your `webpack.mix.js`

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.config.fileLoaderDirs.fonts = 'assets/fonts';
```

Comment: Not working on current Laravel-mix version 6.0.16. Getting this error: `Cannot read property 'fileLoaderDirs' of undefined`

Comment: I just figured out, on recent versions of Laravel-mix (6.0) replace `config` by `options`, so it will work as intended: `mix.options.fileLoaderDirs.fonts = 'assets/fonts'`

Comment: you can do like this: mix.options({
    fileLoaderDirs: {
        fonts: 'assets/fonts'
    },
});

Answer (score 16):

Try to copy them directly like this:

```
mix.copyDirectory('assets/font-awesome/webfonts', 'public/fonts');
```

Or you can copy files one by one:

```
mix.copy('assets/font-awesome/webfonts/example.ttf', 'public/fonts/example.ttf');
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @farid-hatami answer, you can also append to the generated URL with.

```
mix.setResourceRoot('/public')
```

This is useful if you're running backends like Django where you have to be explicit with your url.

Answer (score 3):

Mix options have changed. Use instead:

```js
mix.options({
    fileLoaderDirs:  {
        fonts: 'assets/fonts'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just change the way Laravel Mix generates the folder structure by overwriting the Webpack rule that manages fonts.

The original rule can be found in the Laravel Mix package, in `src/builder/webpack-rules.js`, line 50, where the comment says `// Add support for loading fonts`.

In your Mix file you can overwrite the rule with the webpackConfig method, like this:

```js
mix.webpackConfig({
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /(\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|otf)$|font.*\.svg$)/,
      loaders: [{
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: (path) => {
            if (!/node_modules|bower_components/.test(path)) {
              return 'fonts/[name].[ext]?[hash]';
            }
            return (
              'fonts/vendor/' +
              path
              .replace(/\\/g, '/')
              .replace(
                /((.*(node_modules|bower_components))|fonts|font|assets)\//g,
                ''
              ) +
              '?[hash]'
            );
          },
        },
      }],
    }],
  },
})
```

The rule I have written is almost identical to the one in the Laravel Mix package, so if you need to change it you will have to update one of the two returns: in this case the second one, because the fonts come from an npm module.

So instead of

```js
path
  .replace(/\\/g, '/')
  .replace(
    /((.*(node_modules|bower_components))|fonts|font|assets)\//g,
  ''
)
```

you can write an hard-coded string or change what you want out of the original path: in this way the folder structure in the original node module (in this case Font Awesome) won't affect the folder structure of your `public` folder.