# Include @font-face in SAS Swithout Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, sass, font-awesome

I have a problem including fonts into a SASS file within Laravel. I'm aware of Laravel Mix, but I'd like to find a solution without using it. All of my fonts are in public/assets/fonts. I've tried different syntaxes as adding public_path to the URL or with ../ or only the name of the font with the format but no way to get the font.

```
file.scss

@font-face {
      font-family: 'Klavika Regular';
      src: url('assets/fonts/Klavika Regular.otf') format('otf');
      }
```

Comment: Where is your .scss file is located ?

Comment: in this path : resources/sass/scss-public

Comment: But your scss file is compiled right ? how do you compile it ? you surely use Mix ?

Comment: You should look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50860679/laravel-mix-generate-fonts-into-another-directory

Comment: @VincentDecaux i compile it  to  min.css in public/css folder.

Comment: @VincentDecaux and yes iI'm not using mix laravel .

Comment: @VincentDecaux the solution you send is with mix :(  there is no solution to do it without laravel mix  you think ?

Comment: You should add a preceding slash `/` to indicate that the `assets` folder is relative to the site root `src: url('/assets/fonts/...')`.  Mix can be very helpful but is definitely not required.

Comment: @matticustard no it doesn't work :/

Comment: What happens if you try to access the file directly  `http://yourdomain.com/assets/fonts/Klavika Regular.otf`?

Comment: I mean from your browser, not in the SCSS.

Comment: @matticustard it gives me a 404 error , and i think it's logic , since i'm working with laravel and all url that d'ont have a route will not work . no ?

Comment: If it gives you a 404 error, then your font files are either not present in the directory where you say they are, or the public root of your server is pointed at the wrong directory.  It should be pointed at the `/public` folder.

Comment: I found the issue , it was because i used the format 
`src: url('assets/fonts/Klavika Regular.otf') format('otf');`
i should write only this instead : 
` src: url('assets/fonts/Klavika Regular.otf')`